# Postgres gives error while setting parameter in db level

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pgvector

I dump a database from one postgres db using `pg_dump` and restore to another postgres database (In RDS) using `pg_restore`. But at that time I forget to using `--no-owner`. After restoring, I change owner to `postgres` user. I am using `pgvector` extension and when I try to set config parameter `hnsw.ef_search` on database level it gives me error `permission denied to set parameter 'hnsw.ef_search'`.

Command to set parameter on database level

```sql
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET hnsw.ef_search = 500;
```

Please help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

PS : when I create new db and try to run same query, it will execute without any error.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `SELECT` query on vector column on same database executing as it is used in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because the shared library for the extension `vector` (which is `vector.so`) is not loaded in the current session. Until the library is loaded, `hnsw.ef_search` is not defined and treated as a “placeholder parameter” by PostgreSQL. Only a superuser can use `ALTER DATABASE` to set a value for a placeholder parameter.

`hnsw.ef_search` gets redefined as a regular parameter as soon as `vector.so` is loaded in the current session. So you should call a function from the extension, `SELECT` from a table that uses the `vector` data type or do something else that causes `vector.so` to be loaded into the backend process of the current session. Then run your `ALTER DATABASE` statement in that same session, and it should succeed.